# Can a Ba'al Qeri act as Shaliahh Tzibbur?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, chazzan-prayer-leader, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, tefillah-betzibbur

The question arises in the Halakhah ([Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef, Orahh Hayim 88:1](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0017_L2)) as to whether a *Ba'al Qeri* (one who has recently released his seed) is permitted to read Qeri'at Shema' and to pray Shemoneh 'Esrei.

Given that, per Yalqut Yosef, a Ba'al Qeri is indeed allowed to perform these mitzwot, is he also permitted to act as Shaliahh Tzibbur?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although there is a custom to go to the *mikva* each morning, widespread in some circles, that custom is uncommon even in some of the most religious circles, and I have never in all my years heard of any hesitation to acting as prayer leader based on issues of *keri* in communities where that custom is rare.

Comment: No pun intended.

Comment: "I have never in all my years heard of any hesitation to acting as prayer leader based on issues of *keri*". That is simply [not true](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/35061/revisions)!

Comment: @NBZ You're right! I forgot about that question. Thanks for the correction. Lemme edit this answer....